# Never ending loop in displaying LinkedList in C++

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

In the following code when i try to display the list after removing the first element, its resulting in endless loop of next elements. This problem doesn't occur when other than first element is removed. I have no clue why is this happening? Can someone please tell me where is the mistake?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
  int data;
  node *link;

};

class linkedlist
{  node *head;
public:
linkedlist()
{
   head=NULL;
}
    int add(int data1)
    { node *insertnode=new node;
        insertnode->data=data1;
        insertnode->link=NULL;

        node *temp=head;

        if(temp!=NULL)
        {
            while(temp->link!=NULL)
            {
                temp=temp->link;
            }
            temp->link=insertnode;

        }
        else{head=insertnode;}

    }
    void disp()
    { node *temp1=head;
    cout<<endl;
    if(temp1==NULL)
    {cout<<"Empty"<<endl;
    }
    if(temp1->link==NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp1->data<<endl;

    }
    else{
    do{cout<<temp1->data<<endl;
    temp1=temp1->link;
    }
    while(temp1!=NULL);
    }

    }

    int remove(int removedata)
    {
        node *temp2=head;
        if(temp2==NULL)
         {}

         if(temp2->link==NULL)
         {
             delete temp2;
             head=NULL;
         }

         else
         {
             node *previous;
             do
             {
                 if(temp2->data==removedata) break;
                 previous=temp2;
                 temp2=temp2->link;
             }while(temp2!=NULL);

            previous->link=temp2->link;
             delete temp2;
         }


    }



};

int main()
{
   linkedlist list;
   list.add(10);
   list.add(100);
   list.add(200);
   list.remove(10);
   list.disp();
}
```

Thank you all. The problem has been solved

Comment: Show us the output please If there is a cycle in the list, this behavior is expected - you cannot really know when the list ends without some extra work

Comment: did you try to debug it?

Comment: `if(temp2==NULL) {}` ???

Comment: what happens when in the first insertion (head Is NULL)?

Comment: @amit the output is 100 200, then again 100 200. it goes on like this. how can i capture output in such situations so that i can display?

Comment: What are the values of `previous` and `temp2` after the loop when you removed the first element? What is the value of `head` after the removal? (Pencil and paper are the best debugging tools here.)

Comment: @trojanfoe i tried `if(temp2==NULL) {return;}` but getting error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look on your deletion:

```
    node *previous;
         do
         {
             if(temp2->data==removedata) break;
             previous=temp2;
             temp2=temp2->link;
         }while(temp2!=NULL);

        previous->link=temp2->link;
         delete temp2;
```

If the first element is the matched one, the loop will immidaiately terminate, resulting in **uninitializing `previous`**, and not changing `temp2` (it is still the head).

What you will now do is:

1. set `previous->link` to some value. Note that this is **undefined behavior**, since you have no idea what `previous` is.
2. delete `temp2` - which is the head element, but never changing the head. This will result that the first element in the list is undefined, and once accessing it anything can happen (again, undefined behavior).

So, basically - after you delete the first element - when you try to display the list, anything can happen - including the infinite loop you are encountering.

Comment: Thanks.Now i have rectified it. Now facing entirely different problem. I have added the details in edit

Comment: @Vinay: If it solved your last problem, and you are encountering a new one - you should probably post it as a new question.

Comment: thanks mate. I shall post it as a new problem. I have accepted your's as an answer.:)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120131/head-not-linked-correctly-in-linked-list) is not entirely unrelated. You've only addressed half of the problem, `head` is not being set when the first element is removed.

Comment: @Johnsyweb:  I think I did: "2....but never changing the head. this will result that the first element in the list is undefined"

Comment: Sorry, @amit, by "you" I meant "Vinay" in the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't adjust your pointer to the head. Guess that's why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the first element, you have to point the head of the list to the next element. You didn't do that here.

Answer (score 0):

In `disp()`, you access `temp1->link`, whether `temp1` is NULL or not

```
if(temp1==NULL)
{cout<<"Empty"<<endl;
}
if(temp1->link==NULL)
{
    cout<<temp1->data<<endl;

}
```

Same for `temp2` in `remove()`.

`node *previous;` is used uninitialized, when the first node is removed.